# C# illegal characters in the path

Tags: c#

I am getting illegal characters in the path by using the below codes:

```
string fileNameExisting = Application.StartupPath + "\\CodesLocation\\Template.pdf";
PdfReader templateFile = new PdfReader(fileNameExisting);
```

I tested a few variations:

```
string fileNameExisting = @Application.StartupPath + "\CodesLocation\Template.pdf";
PdfReader templateFile = new PdfReader(fileNameExisting);
```

But it is still getting the same illegal error.

Can anyone help me see if my code if wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you output `fileNameExisting` so we can see what the illegal characters are.

Comment: Check Application.StartupPath value and share.

Comment: It is c:\Projects... Let me try the answers n revert if any issue

Comment: It's showing C:\Projects\CodesLocation\Template.pdf... It is still getting the same illegal error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest using the appropriate way to join paths in .net:
[Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784047)

So

```
Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "CodesLocation","Template.pdf");
```

Comment: Let me try when i have my laptop with me... Anyway thanks for the prompt assistance

Comment: It's showing C:\Projects\CodesLocation\Template.pdf... It is still getting the same illegal error.

Answer (score 3):

An at in front of a string literal turns off `\` escaping (in front of a variable it explicitly marks a variable as *not a keyword*):

```
Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"CodesLocation\Template.pdf");
```

And `Path.Combine` is the state of the art way to concatenate paths (platform independent, takes care of additional slashed).

Answer (score 2):

You should best use
`Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "CodesLocation\\Template.pdf")`. 
Other than that check if Application.StartupPath ends with `\`.

Comment: The Application.StartupPath does not ends with \ and it is still not working with the Path.Combine.